# There is a deployment descriptor in every folder. What's happening?

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, eclipse-wtp

The project is a gradle project in the eclipse environment. I received the project from someone else and imported it, and I see deployment descriptors created in all folders. I don't think this should happen, but how can I fix this error?
Java is using 11 and Tomcat is using 9.0.
(ps. The folder name has been hidden for security reasons.)

[image]

I imported the project several times and tried importing it by reinstalling the 2023-06 and 2022-03 versions of Eclipse.

Comment: You can clean build your project or just right click on the project folder and refresh it.

Comment: I tried everything and it's the same...

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to the [bug report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=182136) and reopen it.

Comment: A new image is not, by itself, a reproducible example. For the most basic information, there aren't actually web.xml files in each folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse has once recorded this bug. You can check your eclipse version. I have provided the link in which this bug was reported.
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=182136

Comment: Well, someone reported it to Eclipse without a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so it got closed.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to update the version in web.xml, which will then force update maven

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
                         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web- 
        app_3_1.xsd"
        version="3.1">
        <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
      <!-- Your configuration goes here -->
   </web-app>
```